# Selecting multiple index values in a pandas series

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a Pandas Series:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3], index=['a','b','c'])
foo

a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64
```

Comparing the index to a value returns a nice selector array:

```
foo.index == 'c'

array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

What is the expression for a selector array for 'a' and 'c' ([True, False, True])?

Not this:

```
foo.index in ['a', 'c']

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This is a simple example, but the true one is more complicated, and I want to select 10 or 15 items, so I'd like a concise format, ideally listing the elements I want to select by name.

I'm using pandas 0.23.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
foo.index.isin(['a','b'])
```

which returns your selector array for `a` and `b`, you can arbitrarily change the list if different values are required.